# Using Twig to separate design stuff from index.php

Tags: php, logic, twig, theory

i've started to code my own browsergame and heard about Twig PHP. I read some things in the documentation, but i didnt found any way to include this system completly into my source structure.

**My php structure is like that:**
The "index.php" in root directory includes the content-site, which i've got from the global $_GET[]

```
<?php
// doing some stuff ..
include($dir_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . htmlspecialchars($_GET['site']) . ".php");   
?>
```

In this content-site(lets take for example: news.php) im using classes and doing some stuff.
After i got all information, i put them in an array for using them in Twig:

```
<?php
// doing some stuff ..
$array = returnOfMyFunctions(); // just for example!

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templateDir');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('news.html');
$template->display($array);
?>
```

**Easier said:**
index.php => include("news.php") => display the "news.html" template

**My Goal:**
I want to create an environment for designers, where they cant use PHP and Javascript (i can just filter it through Twig template). So javascript can be included through my index.php in the html header section(i have a function adding all the js files depending on my $_GET variable).

**But here comes my problem:**
The designers should edit my main page too. What i mean? Its for example my index.php(not the file itself, just the template!). Because in my index.php file im not just including all the content-sites, but also the header, the navigation and so on. So the real problem is here, how can i export the design stuff from my index.php to a template file.(Because they shouldn't have access to my index.php. But they should have the option to design my main page. Making div tags around my included content-site and positioning my navigation and so on. So my idea was about including just a Twig template in my index.php, where the designer can move the included content-site and design writing his own div tags like he wants to.

**For example an index.html template file:**

```
<div id="header"> {{ header }} </div> // INCLUDE the header
<div id="leftnavigation"> {{ left-navigation }} </div> // INCLUDE the left navigation
<div id="rightnavigation"> {{ right-navigation }} </div> // INCLUDE the right navigation
<div id="contentsite"> {{ content-site }} </div> // INCLUDE the content-site
<div id="footer"> {{ footer }} </div> // INCLUDE the footer
```

I've read in the Twig Documentation that i can include functions and its just easy, but i dont think i should execute a function in a template file, which includes the content-site.

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
$function = new Twig_SimpleFunction('function_name', function () {
    // including the content-site in which another Twig template is loaded. (for ex: news.html)
});
$twig->addFunction($function);
```

I've read in the documentation some stuff about inherit a child template, but it doesnt seem to be the solution too..

Or am I just thinking about nonsense stuff and should make some div tags in my index.php file and give the designers no access to my index.php file, but just to the css file where they can edit the div classes of my index.php file? Im not sure, if thats enough for a designer.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me say that all of this is very messy. My personnal suggestion would be for you to use a framework, to cleanly separate your logic in controllers, and the views in a separate directory. This way your designers can do their magic without having to know anything about what the PHP is about.

About your concern about inheriting templates in TWIG, it is a very good practice to have. It allows to define on deferent layers the elements of your view. For example you have a base.html.twig layout where you put the navbar you want on all pages of your site. Then, you write another template that inherits from this base (`{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}`), and it will have all the elements you have defined in base. Realy powerful way to avoid duplicating HTML code.

So, to sum up, separate your code into different layers (use MVC pattern or n-tier structure) and use TWIG inheritance, and all of this should become a lot cleaner and easy to work with.